# What is the advantage of shifting the pointer 32 bytes in EVM?

Tags: evm

WyvernExchange takes an offset of 32 bytes at the beginning and puts it back in the keccak256 calculation.
What is the advantage of taking a 32-byte offset in this way?

https://github.com/ProjectWyvern/wyvern-ethereum/blob/bfca101b2407e4938398fccd8d1c485394db7e01/contracts/exchange/ExchangeCore.sol#L259-L261

Answer (score 0):

From the declaration `array` is a memory bytes array. For memory arrays the firs 32 bytes contain the array's length.

```
    bytes memory array = new bytes(size);
```

So it is skipping bytes occupied with the length, directly to the data portion.

```
    uint index;
    assembly {
        index := add(array, 0x20)
    }
```

The purpose seems to write at the array data pointed by index, and update index to the next unused part

```
    index = ArrayUtils.unsafeWriteAddress(index, order.exchange);
```

It seems to be doing something similar to abi.encodePacked.